# Fluxbox time is wrong?

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, time, fluxbox

I'm using fluxbox on Arch, and the time is displayed incorrectly in the panel. The time works in XFCE, so I'm not sure why it isn't working in fluxbox.

Is there a way to set the time in fluxbox from the internet?

Comment: Is 'date' on a terminal showing right time? Did you set 'TZ' variable on your environment? you could check it with: 'env | grep TZ'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with

```
# hwclock --set --date="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your system has a connection to the internet, use NTP to set up the time. For arch Linux, you can find the instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Time_Protocol).